# Fetch/Scrape Data from multiple/dynamic pages (accessible with a base url and query parameter) through a loop using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I have been trying to scrape some data off a website as a practice to hone my python skills. The page contains a list of cards containing company details (50 per page it seems) and a navigation below that points to base url + page-number params like `https://clutch.co/uk/app-developers?page=3`

I am stuck at a point where if I create new requests for each urls (base url + page number params)  and get the data using multiple (post) requests the data is fetched correctly `(new data for each url just as I wanted)`, however when I put those steps in a loop `(generating the url through for loop and params)` I get the result only from the first page (though the results are repeated for a times specified in the loop).

Here's the code I've tried with two different outcome:

```
#Base code for the project 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = 'https://clutch.co/uk/app-developers?page='
urls = [base_url + str(x) for x in range(0, 21)]
s = requests.Session()

#Function to extract link href from each element in bs4 object
def get_profile_link(profile_links, profiles=[]):
    for link in profile_links:
        profiles.append(link['href'])
    return profiles
```

**Method 1: This works and gives me data from 2 pages (100 unqiue results)**

```
r1 = s.post(urls[0])
soup1 = bs(r1.content)
links1 = soup1.find_all('a', attrs={'data-link_text': "Profile Button"})
list1 = get_profile_link(links1)

r2 = s.post(urls[1])
soup2 = bs(r2.content)
links2 = soup2.find_all('a', attrs={'data-link_text': "Profile Button"})
list2 = get_profile_link(links2, list1)
```

**Method 2: However this doesn't work and gives me 100 results with only 50 unique values**

```
#A simplified version of loop to fetch results (I have a slightly complex one that generates url within the loop). 

for x in range(0, 2):
    r = s.post(urls[x])
    soup = bs(r.content)
    links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-link_text': "Profile Button"})
    list = get_profile_link(links)
```

Looking for guidance on what I am doing wrong in the **Method 2**, so I can use loop to extract the links. I think it might work through use of cookies and I checked `print(r.cookies)` and it seems cookies is not generated/empty. I read through the docs but couldn't figure this out clearly.

Do let me know if further details required.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to not use list default parameters in functions (eg. `profiles=[]`).

Also, don't use built-in names as variable names (eg. `list`).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# Function to extract link href from each element in bs4 object
def get_profile_link(profile_links):
    rv = []
    for link in profile_links:
        rv.append(link["href"])
    return rv


all_data = []
base_url = "https://clutch.co/uk/app-developers?page="
with requests.session() as s:
    for page in range(0, 2):
        url = base_url + str(page)
        soup = bs(s.post(url).content, "html.parser")
        links = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"data-link_text": "Profile Button"})
        all_data.extend(get_profile_link(links))

print("Length of data:", len(all_data))
print("Unique elements:", len(set(all_data)))
```

Prints:

```
Length of data: 100
Unique elements: 100
```

Comment: I was using default parameters, since I wanted function to be accept an existing list and add items to it, instead of returning a new one, which I would have to extend/concatenate/flattened. Noted about the list, guess I would have changed it while reviewing the code. P.S. I couldn't get what I was doing wrong, could you elaborate on that. Will try the solution you posted tomorrow and see the final outcome. Thanks.